# Wireless keyboard on iPad2

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I finally got my wireless keyboard for my iPad and I'm quite disappointed. Beside the media controls the whole stuff from the dock-keyboard doesn't work on the wireless one. What's even worse is that I have to disconnect the keyboard when I take the iPad away from the desk and go to the balcony. Is there any way to get the soft-keypad back, when the wireless keyboard is connected without going to the keyboard and pressing the eject-key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems very similar to this one:
[Re-enabling virtual iPad keyboard with paired Bluetooth keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11830/re-enabling-virtual-ipad-keyboard-with-paired-bluetooth-keyboard)

I think that the same answers will apply.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> General -> Bluetooth and switch bluetooth off.

Comment: Sure, but it's kind of annoying. At the moment, I always turn off bluetooth for a second to disconnect the keyboard, as I usually realize the soft-pad is not there when the keyboard is out of reach.

Comment: Alright I have the answer for you, see my edited answer!

Comment: Uhm, that's what I wrote. "[...] turn off bluetooth for a second [...]". It's just inconvenient.

Comment: OK the only suggestion I have is to jailbreak your iPad, and get SBSettings, which lets you enable or disable bluetooth quicker, and from anywhere.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I'm not a big fan of jailbreaking, but I'll keep that in mind.