# How to show a keyboard when an iOS device is connected with a barcode scanner and keyboard gets hidden by scanner

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

How can I show the keyboard manually from an iOS app when a scanner is connected via Bluetooth to an iOS device? When scanning an item, the scanner automatically hides the keyboard in an iOS app but we want the keyboard to always be visible. Though it has the functionality to show the keyboard by double pressing the side button, we don't want users to keep pressing buttons repeatedly.

From online sources, I cannot figure out any solution, whether I can do it programmatically in Swift or in another language or we can't do it in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this:

- Press and hold the Language Chevron
- Press the Eject Key
- Create a barcode that maps to the Eject key

Both of these methods require you to select the text field. Simply tap the field to select it.  If not selected, the on-screen keyboard won’t appear. This feature will remain “enabled” (for the session at least) until you hide the keyboard again.

#### Language Chevron

When you’re in a text field, the keyboard toolbar will show  at the bottom of the screen.  Press and hold the Language Indicator (“EN” shown below) to bring up the context menu then select “Show Keyboard”

[image]

[image]

#### Eject Key

If you’re using a keyboard and it has an Eject key, simply select the text field and press “Eject.”

[image]

<sup>This answer was written on an iPad running iOS 16.4.1 with a Logitech K380 Bluetooth Keyboard and MX Anywhere BT Mouse Mouse.  Both methods described above were tested as this answer was written.</sup>

#### Create an "Eject Button Barcode"

Unfortunately, I can't detail how to do this as every barcode scanner manufacturer uses a different process and programming instructions would be out of scope here.  However, since your barcode scanner is identified as a keyboard and as long as your scanner supports it, you can send Function/Control Keys (eject = 0x0C) when a barcode is scanned.

For example, my Symbol/Metrologic MS1690 scanner supports this function in all modes.  Therefore, I can create a barcode that when scanned will send the "eject" key sequence to trigger the virtual keyboard on my iPad.

This will require you obtaining the programming/supplemental guide specific to your scanner from the manufacturer.

[image]

Comment: Did you *test* it @Thinkr or are you guessing?

Comment: And you propose they make the keyboard appear automagically?  How is selecting the text field *once per session* = “keep pressing buttons”?

Comment: Yeah, you must be right.